# Multiple components in JPanel not displayed

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

I have tried many solutions but I do not know what is wrong with my code.
Basicaly I want to display the shapes in the window, FlowLayout does not display anything and BorderLayout displays the last one which is not what I want. Ignore the shape.draw() method, it just prints coordinates of the shape. Shape extends JComponent.

```
package Shapes;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

/**
 * Created by Matej on 10/12/2016.
 */

public class TestShapes extends JFrame
{
    //static Shape[] shapes = new Shape[3];
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Shape[] shapes = new Shape[3];
        shapes[0] = new Circle(300,100,20);
        shapes[1] = new Rectangle(100,100,40,60);
        shapes[2] = new RedRectangle(200,200,20,30);

        TestShapes window = new TestShapes();

        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(500,500);

        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        for(Shape shape:shapes)
        {
            shape.printName();
            shape.draw();
            panel.add(shape);
        }

        window.add(panel);
        window.setVisible(true);

    }

    public void paint (Graphics g)
    {
        super.paint(g);
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) See [Detection/fix for the hanging close bracket of a code block](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251795/155831) for a problem I could no longer be bothered fixing. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) **For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).**

Comment: *"Shape extends JComponent."* It probably should not extend anything. But if it does extend `JComponent`, it should also override `getPreferredSize()` to give size hints to the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've not shown us your code for your Shape class and subclass, but regardless you're doing it wrong, and the fix is to **not have them extend JComponent**. Rather make them **logical** not **component** classes, and pass them into a JPanel that holds them in an `ArrayList<...>` and that draws them in its paintComponent method override. Then add this JPanel to your JFrame's contentPane, BorderLayout.CENTER, so that it may display its contained shapes.

Note that JComponents default to a preferred size of 0,0 unless they have been given other reason not to -- such as if they hold components that have preferred size or if they have an overridden `getPreferredSize()` method.

But again this is moot, because you're not wanting to display each figure in its own component as this will unnecessarily limit what you can do with the images and where you can display them.